# FeaturePlot of Seurat Metadata

Tags: r, seurat

Say I have a Seurat object called seur whose metadata includes a column named "count" (list of doubles) that displays how many time a certain cell appears. I want to use the FeaturePlot tool to plot the counts on my UMAP so I can see where the high counts are via the color gradient.

Yet, when I do:

```
FeaturePlot(seur, features = "count")
```

I get the error:

```
count.Error in if (unique.feature.exp == 0) { : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

How do I solve this error and/or correctly use FeaturePlot?

Comment: Are you sure `"count"` is a feature? I haven't used Seurat in a bit, but my old code shows using `"nUMI"` for total UMI counts per cell or `"nGene"` for unique genes per cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, check you have Seurat 3 or Seurat 4, I am on using Seurat_3.2.2 below:

```
library(Seurat)
seur = pbmc_small
eur$count = rpois(ncol(seur),5)
FeaturePlot(seur,features="count")
```

[image]